# Set TextView to display integers that change for a certain length of time

Tags: android, textview

I would like to add a TextView to my layout that holds an integer value and continues to change it's value for some length of time. For example, the TextView could change its value for 10 seconds and then stops. How can I do this?

Comment: show your efforts and if any problem then ask

Comment: check this example. http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/os/handler/android-timer-example/

Comment: I should put some code here. Otherwise is hard to help you.

Comment: Have you had any luck with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to look into a [CountdownTimer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html). The code would look something like this:

```
CountDownTimer myCountDown = new CountDownTimer(10000, 1000){
   public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
      myTextView.SetText(String.valueOf(millisUntilFinished / 10));
   }

   public void onFinish() {
      myTextView.SetText("Done!");
   }
}.start();
```

This will create a timer that runs for 10 seconds and updates the TextView every second. an important thing to note is that the parameters are in milliseconds, not seconds. The first parameter (10,000 in my example) represents the duration of the timer. The second parameter (1,000) determines how many milliseconds occur between each call to `onTick()`.

Comment: Thank you Sir. It helped a lot.

Comment: @KishoreL glad I could help!